# Using C++ namespaces inside of inline assembly code

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I just have a quick question on if this will work on or not.

```
void __declspec(naked) HookProcessEventProxy() {
__asm {
    mov CallObjectPointer, ecx
        push edx
        mov edx, dword ptr[esp + 0x8]
        mov UFunctionPointer, edx
        mov edx, dword ptr[esp + 0xC]
        mov ParamsPointer, edx
        pop edx
        pushfd
        pushad

}
ProcessEventProxy();
__asm {
    popad
        popfd
        jmp[Pointers::OldProcessEvent] // This is the line in question.
   }
}
```

Does the Pointers namespace define to go to the `Pointers::OldProcessEvent` or will it go to the `ProcessEvent` I have inside of my `DLLMain`?
The `HookProcessEventProxy` is inside my `DLLMain`.

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: What did the compiler do when you tried it?

Comment: The compiler does not find it as a error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the vendor-specific extensions in the code, it seems that you are compiling this on MSVC. If so, then this is not a problem. The inline assembler understands C++ scoping rules and identifiers.

You can easily verify this for yourself by analyzing the object code produced by the compiler. Either disassemble the binary using `dumpbin /disasm`, or throw the `/FA` switch when running the compiler to get a separate listing. What you'll see is that the compiler emits your inline assembly in a very literal fashion:

```
?HookProcessEventProxy@@YAXXZ PROC                  ; HookProcessEventProxy, COMDAT
    mov     DWORD PTR ?CallObjectPointer@@3HA, ecx  ; CallObjectPointer
    push    edx
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [esp+8]
    mov     DWORD PTR ?UFunctionPointer@@3HA, edx   ; UFunctionPointer
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [esp+12]
    mov     DWORD PTR ?ParamsPointer@@3HA, edx      ; ParamsPointer
    pop     edx
    pushfd
    pushad
    call    ?ProcessEventProxy@@YAXXZ               ; ProcessEventProxy
    popad
    popfd
    jmp     ?OldProcessEvent@Pointers@@YAXXZ        ; Pointers::OldProcessEvent
?HookProcessEventProxy@@YAXXZ ENDP                  ; HookProcessEventProxy
```

The above listing is from the file generated by the compiler when the `/FA` switch is used. The comments out to the right indicate the corresponding C++ object.

Note that you do not need the brackets around the branch target. Although the inline assembler ignores them, it is confusing to include them. Just write:

```
jmp Pointers::OldProcessEvent
```